# Pug conditional check if value in list

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Is there a way to check if a value is in a collection in pug? Something like

```
unless user.id in allUsers.ids
  //- do something
```

where `allUsers` is a list of user objects like

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tom'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jerry'
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this, but I was able to solve it by passing in a function that would lookup in the array and return true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pug's conditionals](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) are "just regular JavaScript" with two exceptions:

- the parentheses are optional
- `unless` works like a negated `if`.

Thus, there's no need to pass a custom lookup function for Pug. You can instead use the regular [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
unless allUsers.find((u) => u.id === user.id)
  //- user not found; do something
```